# urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python

Я пытался проверить какая ошибка будет, если ввести неправильную ссылку `Url = "https://www.gooFgle.com.ua/search?"`.

И получил эту ошибку: `"urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"`

P.S. Я импортировал все нужные модули.

```
try:
    Url = "https://www.gooFgle.com.ua/search?"
    otvet = request.urlopen(Url)
    value = {'q':'Andesa Soft'}
    mydata = parse.urlencode(value)
    print(mydata)

    Url = Url + mydata
    req = request.Request(Url)
    otvet = request.urlopen(req)
    otvet = otvet.readlines()
    for line in otvet:
        print(line)

except Exception as e:
    print("Errors while request!")
    print("Error:", e)
    print(sys.exc_info()[1]
    print()

    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что не удалось получить по указанному хосту адрес (скорее всего ip и port), т.е. в коде все правильно. Я немного код подправил и добавил пример для получения больше информации из исключения

Comment: Замечаний по коду много, но лучше почитайте стандарт оформления когда питона: http://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/. ЗЫ. вместо `otvet` лучше `response` или просто `rs`

Comment: Спасибо!Обязательно почитаю.Только сегодня зарегистрировался на этом сайте)Не знал что так быстро ответят.

Comment: Почему у меня эта ошибка , а у друга HTTP Error 404: Not found?

Answer (score -1):

[`socket.getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) используется, чтобы для сервиса на заданном узле получить информацию необходимую для создания сокета, подключённого к этому сервису.

Если вы указываете несуществующее имя узла, то ожидаемо происходит ошибка (dns запрос неудачный).

---

Ошибка 404 уже относится к http протоколу — она требует чтобы удачно dns запрос прошёл, если вы по имени хост задаёте. HTTP 404 Not Found статус возвращает http-сервер: это значит вы успешно подсоединились, но указанного пути http-сервер не нашёл. Иногда это ещё может означать, что необходимо было пароль указать (пример: github.com).